# Trying to create Search Bar via PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the HTML:

```
<body>
<p>Search</p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="searchresults.php">
<input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="search">

</form>
</body>
```

Below is the PHP:

```
<?php
    require_once '../database/config.php';

    if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
        header("Location: ads.index.php");
    }
    $search_sql="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%" .$_POST['search']."%' OR description LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
    $result = $dbc->query($search_sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) {    
    $search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    ?>
    <p>Search Results</p>
    <?php if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) {
        do { ?>
    <p><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?></p>
    <?php   } while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    } 
    ?>
```

What is wrong here? I keep getting an error when trying to search in the database - it says the mysql_num_rows function is deprecated, I don't understand how to replace it.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should not use them.

Comment: How should I refactor the code to replace mysql_num_rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your `$dbc` to use the latest one, either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) will do. For now, changing your code:

```
<?php
  require_once '../database/config.php';

  if (!isset($_POST['search']))
    header("Location: ads.index.php");

  // create the connection object
  $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  // Don't forget to sanitize your user queries.
  // Here $conn is the connection object I assume. Replace it with yours.
  $_POST['search'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
  $search_sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%" . $_POST['search'] . "%' OR `description` LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
  // change the result here.
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $search_sql);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
    $search_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }

  ?>
  <p>Search Results</p>
  <?php
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    do { ?>
      <p><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?></p>
  <?php
    // Kindly note, how false and assignment is used here.
    } while (false != ($search_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)));
  }
  else
    echo "No results found";
?>
```

If you are interested, there's also an open source project [**Converting to MySQLi**](https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool) in GitHub.

And regarding more information about why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions, read **[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**

Comment: $conn - Undefined variable
mysqli_real_escape_string() - expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
mysqli_num_rows() - expects paramteter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: @sshaikh210 **Did you read my comments or blindly copied it without reading? `// Here $conn is the connection object I assume. Replace it with yours.`**

Comment: And also @sshaikh210, **Please change your `$dbc` to use the latest one.**

Comment: I copied, what do I replace it for?

Comment: @sshaikh210 Kindly share how you get your `$dbc`. Please provide the source of `'../database/config.php'`.

Comment: $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . '','' . DB_USER . '','' . DB_PASS . '');

$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: @sshaikh210 Kindly [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34517166/edit) the post and update. But it looks like you are already using PDO. Why are you using `mysql_*` functions with PDO?

Comment: Also I don't believe I have MySQLi installed - Do you know how to replace it with PDO_MySQL?

Comment: @sshaikh210 No I don't know. I believe you have **MySQLi** installed. Because it comes bundled. Try using `phpinfo();` and check if you have `mysqli_*` installed.

Comment: @sshaikh210 I have updated my code. Kindly copy and paste and tell me if you get any errors.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the last error I am getting:
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: @sshaikh210 Updated answer.

Comment: Multiple - Undefined index: name in - errors on Line 24 "<p><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?></p>"

Comment: @sshaikh210 Try giving `$search_rs[0];` or `$search_rs[1];` until you get the right result. Change `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` to `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`, please?

Comment: @sshaikh210 Did it work?

Comment: Can you explain to me what that means? $search_rs[0] or [1]? What does the incremented numbers do for the variable?

Comment: @sshaikh210 Not associative, but by column index.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its producing some things correctly - when I search for something not in the database it produces the right result "No results found" but when I search for something in the database it does not produce the row correctly.

Comment: @sshaikh210 What's wrong? What do you mean by "it does not produce the row correctly"?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks so much Praveen!

Comment: @sshaikh210 Happy Holidays. Enjoy!